# How to setup account with multiple addresses or phone numbers

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I normally program in php (most recently with codeigniter) but this really applies to OOP. I would like to setup a class such as 'Account' where there could be multiple 'ship to' addresses where one is 'active'.

```
class Account
{
  public $name;
  public $status;
}

class Addresses{
  public $Id;
  public $AcctId;
  public $Address;
  public $City;
  public $State;
  public $Zip;
  public $Primary;
  public $Status;
}

DB tables:
tblAccounts
-Id
-Name
-Status

tblAddresses
-Id
-Acctid
-Address
-City
-State
-Zip
-Primary
-Status
```

In CodeIgniter, I believe I need to create a Library to interface with the models, but I am looking for hopefully a tutorial from html form to data in db. I have been unable to find anything that advanced from google but I an sure it is out there somewhere.

Any links to where I can learn/understand how to do this.

All help greatly appreciated.

eg. There is my address and my son's address within tblAddresses associated with my account. How do I populate the Account class with those values so that I can then display/edit/add another? Use a dynamic array of Account->addresses and methods to retrieve/save? Or actual db field in Account that holds Address data say serialized or JSON?

Comment: kindly elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Kindly elaborate your question.

For time being, I think this is what you need....

**1) Create a file with name "Account.php" in your application/controllers.**

write this code in "Account.php" file:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Account extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        if(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)){
             // ........... if form is submitted via POST method
        }else {
            // show form / load view. or do whatever you want if form is not submitted.
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Create a view class. That can be a form. From where you will get user input. and store that values to database.**

**3) Create 2 model classes. (based on how many tables you have in your database).**